# Opening external application from user input

Tags: java, external-application

I want to be able to open an application like internet, notepad, iTunes, and any other .exe file from use input.

Right now I got this;
(ext is the user input)

```
try
{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ext + ".exe");
}
catch(Exception e1){   }
```

This, however, only seems to be able to open notepad, is there any way I can make it so it can open any installed .exe file?

***[NOTE]***

**I'm trying to do this from a java-window I created**

Comment: As much as they preach the transportability of Java, this is completely non-transporta ble.  You OS/X or Linux or Android OS have no idea what ".exe" means.  And what about executables that aren't "exe"s in Windows, like, ".bat" etc.

Comment: I only want to open .exe files

Answer (score 0):

For example this line runs Skype

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/skype.exe");
```

Comment: I'll bet that your `ext` variable needs quotes.  So, something like: `.exec("\"" + ext + "\".exe");`  That may not be quite proper Java, I speak too much C++.

Comment: You can also writ it `exec("C:\\...\\skype.exe")` but `/` slash is more universal. Of course in this case we don't have universality.